# Using Ofice-JS outside a taskpane

Tags: office-js, excel-online

I have an excel-online iframe embedded workbook that is served through WOPI service to client.

I have created a taskpane that auto-loads when you open the document. 
The taskpane does not open in view-mode but works fine in edit-mode.

The goal of having the task-pane was to be able to read the workbook contents (worksheet cells) in view mode using office-js.

Now because the task pane does not load this cannot be done.

Is there a way to use office-js without a taskpane to read Iframe embedded workbook in excel-online view-mode and how can that be done?